# How can i trigger slideNext in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 and i want to trigger slideNext() in my custom function but I don't know how to call slideNext(). Can anyone help me. This is my html code.

```
<ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide class="step-one">
        <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide class="step-two" *ngIf = "verificationCodeSent == 1">
        <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
        <p>Text</p>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide class="step-three" *ngIf = "verificationDone == 1">
        <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
        <h1>Heading 3</h1>
        <p>Text</p>

        <ion-button (click)="finish()">FINISH TUTORIAL!</ion-button>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heres one example of how to use it

.html

```
  <ion-slides pager="true" #theSlides>
<ion-slide class="step-one" (click)="move(theSlides)">
    <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1 >
    <p>Text</p>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide class="step-two" >
    <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide class="step-three" >
    <ion-img src="/assets/icon/favicon.png"></ion-img>
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <p>Text</p>

    <ion-button (click)="finish()">FINISH TUTORIAL!</ion-button>
</ion-slide>
```

.ts

```
move(slides){
    console.log(slides)
    slides.slideTo(2)
}
```

Pass a reference (`#theSlides`) to the slide in the custom function (`move(theSlides)`)